# Spring Boot does not resolve View

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I'am trying to create a simple controller with Spring Boot
Congifuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan (basePackages = { "ru.spb.chat.controller" })
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
       bean.setSuffix(".html");
       return bean;
     }
}
```

and for servlet:

```
 public class MainWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
   @Override
   public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {

       AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root =
               new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

       root.scan("ru.spb");
       sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

       ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet =
            sc.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
       appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
       appServlet.addMapping("/");
    }
```

}

My controller.

```
 @Controller
 public class RootController {

    @GetMapping ("/")
    public String root() {
         return "login";
    }
}
```

But when I try to map on "/" it returns 404-ERROR
This is my project-structure:
[image: structure]

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `WebConfig` and remove your `ServletInitializer` and `MainWebAppInitializer`. (You can probably also remove the `WebSocketConfig` and use the auto-configuration from Spring Boot!).

Let your `ChatApplication` extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and implement the `configure` method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ChatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ChatApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(ChatApplication.class);
  } 

}
```

Then in your `application.properties` add

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Now you are using the proper Spring Boot auto-configuration AND proper way of creating a WAR which is executable.

That being said, you generally don't want a WAR (only if you use JSP, which is discouraged with embedded containers).

Comment: M.Deinum.   I did as you said. But I still have the same problem.

Comment: Your `webapp`  directory is also in the wrong place. It should be in `src/main` not in `src/main/java` where it currently is.

Comment: Yes, you are right.   I corrected this mistake, but have the same problem - 404 error...

Comment: Are you deploying or running the app from the IDE? Which URL are you calling?

Comment: I run from IDE  "ChatApplication" and then. in browser enter: "localhost:8080"

Comment: I add "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf". in dependencies. And now error 404 transformed to error 500 (Error resolving template [login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers)

Comment: If you want to use `Thymeleaf` remove the configuration from the `application.properties` and place your pages in `src/main/resource/templates` (that is the default location used by thymeleaf when auto-configured by spring boot).